# JSON Output Array

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm attempting to output my JSON in a format just like this: http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json and I am unsure of how to accomplish this through my PHP output code.  Right now, It is displaying with "post" at the top and is a map, which I don't know how to successfully remove, seen here: http://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/androidfriendsList.php?username=noah. Please let me know if you need more information.

PHP:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {

    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
        $post = array();
        $post["username"] = $row["username"];
        $post["profile_picture"] = $row["profile_picture"];

        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else 
{   
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "username": "noah",
            "profile_picture": "https://shipstudent.com/animal/appphotos/978321177.jpg"
        },
        {
            "username": "e",
            "profile_picture": "https://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/appphotos/owl.jpeg"
        },
    ]
}
```

Desired format:

```
[{
        "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
        "rating": 8.3,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
    },
    {
        "title": "District 9",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
        "rating": 8,
        "releaseYear": 2009,
        "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$response = [];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $post = [
        "username" => $row["username"],
        "profile_picture" => $row["profile_picture"]
    ];
    $response[] = $post;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Almost, I keep get the error "syntax error, unexpected '['" at $response = [];

Comment: what is your version of php?
if less than 5.4, then use the old syntax for arrays:

`$response = array();`

`$post = array("username" => $row["username"], "profile_picture" => $row["profile_picture"]);`

Comment: And my PHP version is 5.5

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    $post = array();
    $post["title"] => // define title;
    $post["image"] => // define image;
    $post["rating"] => // define rating;
    $post["releaseYear"] => // define releaseYear;
    $post["genre"] => // define genre, must be array();
    array_push($response, $post);
}
```

Comment: This would not work due to it saying unexpected =>  on each line there and when removing it, the server would say unexpected variable...